# What is the word for using one part of speech where another would be more grammatical?

Tags: single-word-requests, vocabulary, parts-of-speech

There's a Greek word that means using the wrong part of speech somewhere in a sentence, as in:

> I don't know the who or the how or the when.

Where "who", "how", and "when" are being used for nouns.  What's the word for this?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The word you're looking for is [anthimeria](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Anthimeria), *artfully using a different part of speech to act as another in violation of the normal rules of grammar*.

This switch might involve treating a verb like a noun, or a noun like a verb, or an adjective like a verb, and so on. Nancy Sinatra's 1960s song *These Boots Are Made for Walkin'* has **You keep lying when you ought to be truthing. . . . You keep saming when you ought to be changing**, for example.

Linguists are much preoccupied with e. e. cummings ["he sang his didn't, he danced his did."](http://journals.cambridge.org/action/displayAbstract?fromPage=online&aid=2728340)

Comment: I love everything about this answer.

Comment: Fixed phrases using anthimeria are _extragrammatical idioms_ (by and large; all of a sudden; long time no see; easy does it ...).